# css sprites not displaying

Tags: html, css, sprite

```
.comments 
{
    clear: both;
    background: url(./img/icons.png) 105px -230px no-repeat;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

<div class="index-tools">
    <span class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link( __( '0', 'html5blank' ), __( '1', 'html5blank' ), __( '%', 'html5blank' )); ?></span>
    <span><?php edit_post_link(); ?></span>
</div>
```

image not showing,I dont know why.
I tried .comments a{...},still not working.
I checked the path using 'Inspect Element',it's showing up,so I guess the path should be right.

what is wrong??

Comment: Try this: `background: url("../img/icons.png") 105px -230px no-repeat;`

Comment: still no, I tried background-position:top center and the image was showing....

Comment: If its on live server, can you share the `URL` of `icons.png`?

Comment: http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/html5blank-master/img/icons.png

Comment: localhost will not work for us

Comment: We won't see that link because is deploy in YOUR localhost server =/

Comment: You can upload icons.png here http://tinypic.com/ and then share generated link

Comment: if you want to see the image,I can send you a link.If you want to check if the path is correct,it should be correct if the inspect element is correct.I have no live server right now..

Comment: http://i43.tinypic.com/10psj2s.png

Comment: if i am using top center left these keywords , it's showing,otherwise no.that's odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`width` and `height` on a span won't work, because a span is an inline element.
Unless the PHP fills the span with some content, it won't have a size and you won't see anything.

So I'd suggest you make it into a inline block.

```
.comments 
{
    clear: both;
    background: url(http://i43.tinypic.com/10psj2s.png) -105px -230px no-repeat;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/EzWvZ/).

I simulated some output from the PHP there, so the text is displayed over the background image, but I guess you'll need to fine-tune that.

Edit: if you want a single rectangular area from a large graphic, the positions must be negative, since you're sliding the graphic up and to the left from its normal location. Otherwise, the large graphic ends up somewhere else than the element it's the background for.
Positive positions would work if you'd be repeating the background.

Comment: OK, what exactly IS the output from the PHP? Can you give an example? And which of the icons in the large graphic do you want to show?

Comment: interesting to notice when I tried some negative positioning,It showed some icon

Comment: Oh that. I presumed that was a typo on your behalf. Yes, the positions need to be negative; since you're sliding the image up and to the left in relation to the span.

Comment: If you mean the icon near the bottom, that one is located at `-82px -1400px` so I'm not sure where you got the `105px -230px` from. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

May be background position getting overridden by other css try `!important` like below;

```
.comments 
{
    clear: both;
    background: url(http://oi43.tinypic.com/10psj2s.jpg) 105px -230px !important;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ent36/1/)

Comment: Don't use `!important` as a panacea. In fact, don't use it, period. If there are situations where you need it, you're doing it wrong.